# Passing current context to str.format?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is it possible to pass the current context (of a function for example) as parameter to format()?

```
def test(a):
    b = Person('b')
    print "{a.name} joins {b.name}".format(???)
```

Is it possible to capture the current function context and pass it to format() as it's possible in ruby with the binding() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`locals()` result dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) as keyword arguments:

```
def test(a):
    b = Person('b')
    print "{a.name} joins {b.name}".format(**locals())
```

`locals()` constructs a dictionary of the local names (in one direction, you cannot use it to *change* the locals). The `**expression` syntax in a [call expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) takes the result of `expression`, and treating it as a mapping uses the key-value pairs as extra keyword arguments.

Demo:

```
>>> class Person(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
... 
>>> def test(a):
...     b = Person('b')
...     print "{a.name} joins {b.name}".format(**locals())
... 
>>> test(Person('a'))
a joins b
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, that works very well. For some addition calculated values I came up with `format(**dict(locals(),child_name=a.name+b.name))`.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: put explicit keyword arguments before it: `.format(child_name=a.name + b.name, **locals())`. No need to construct another dictionary here.